# Bottom navigation bar transaction screens from first screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Am trying to do navigation from one screen to another screen like in will explain in android part.
For implementation of bottom navigation bar am using fragments from first fragment i have a button on click of that button my first screen is moving to second tab of navigation bar like this..

```
((NavigationActivity) getActivity()).navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_screen2);
```

The above line from fragment.
The same how to develop in flutter. thanks in advance.

Comment: check `pageview` - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: i tried with pageview this time EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE exception is comming @anmol.majhil

Comment: Pls Share your code of what you did, then only it can be debugged.

Comment: https://github.com/sujitha123/fluttter_first this is the my repository check it once

Comment: which dart file is having this error .?

Comment: Home.dart file have one button name("View") on click of that button bottom navigation bar moves to next screen ie 0->1 index.

Comment: What you need is Callback, i will write it as Answer. i have tested it also work great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Home.dart` File. You need a Callback to `onTabTapped` function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onTapped;  // CallBack Function

  Home({this.onTapped});

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                        child: Text('WELCOME TO',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text('Travelize',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 192, 103, 1),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                    child: new MaterialButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text("CHECK-IN"),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 192, 103, 1),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                  Center(child: _cardView()),
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: new MaterialButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text("MY VISIT"),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 192, 103, 1),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _lineView() {
    return new Container(
      height: 1.5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(195, 195, 195, 1),
    );
  }

  Widget _cardView() {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 40, left: 40),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 26),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/brandLogos/app_logo.png'))
              ],
            ),
            _lineView(),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'You have',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    ' 0 meetings',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16, color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 192, 103, 1)),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    ' today',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _lineView(),
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: new MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("VIEW"),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 192, 103, 1),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      print(
                          '----dddddddddd------------clicked----------------');
                      widget.onTapped(1);  // Added this.

//                      dashBoardObj.DashboardScreen d =
//                          new dashBoardObj.DashboardScreen();
//                      d.createState().pageController.animateToPage(2,
//                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
//                          curve: Cubic(1, 1, 1, 1));
                    });
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

In your `DashboardScreen.dart`

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(appBarTitle),
      ),
//      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      body: pageView = new PageView(
        physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Home(
            onTapped: onTabTapped,  // pass your function here
          ),
     ......
```